# How to use Python and OpenCV to achieve a well edge detection to calibrate some very small things

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection

I want to use Python and OpenCV to achieve a non-Neural Network edge detection to calibrate some very small things, such as sperms under the microscope. Unfortunately, I found that the sperms' tails are very difficult to calibrate and they're really similar with the background.

I used `cv2.pyrMeanShiftFiltering()` to achieve noise reduction and used `cv2.findContours()` to find contours. The result is like that:

result:

[image: result]
This is the original picture:

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os
path = "/home/rafael/Desktop/2.jpg"

def detection(img):
    gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    #ret, dst = cv.threshold(gray, 200, 255, cv.THRESH_OTSU)
    ret, dst = cv.threshold(gray, 188, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    return dst

image = cv.imread(path)

img = cv.pyrMeanShiftFiltering(src = image, sp = 5, sr = 40)

dst = detection(img)
src, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dst, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv.drawContours(image, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.namedWindow('img', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('img', image)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

I tried Luke's method, and the code is here:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import os

path = "/home/rafael/Desktop/2.jpg"

def enhance(img):
    img = cv.resize(img, (0, 0), fx = 0.3, fy = 0.3)
    blur = cv.GaussianBlur(img, (23, 23), 0)
    img = cv.add(img[:, :, 1], (img[:, :, 1] - blur[:, :, 1]))
    return img

def detection(img):
    ret, dst = cv.threshold(img, 190, 255, cv.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
    return dst

image = cv.imread(path)
img = enhance(image)
dst = detection(img)

src, contours, hierarchy = cv.findContours(dst, cv.RETR_TREE, cv.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
cv.drawContours(img, contours, -1, (0, 0, 255), 2)
cv.namedWindow('img', cv.WINDOW_NORMAL)
cv.imshow('img', img)
cv.waitKey(0)
```

This is the result:
[The latest picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TWkM.png)
Although I used a very big threshold(190), even appeared plenty of noises，the code still couldn't find the tails. How can I solve the problem?
So thanks a lot if anyone could teach me how to improve this simple edge detection program.

Comment: I have edited my question and uploaded the original picture.@Jeru Luke

Comment: You can try to apply some morphological process to be able to make the tails more visible. For example, apply dilation process after you find the edges, so that maybe it may join the small patches of the tail

Comment: I don't think that you mean to "calibrate". Are you trying to measure the tail lengths ?

Comment: This is a very challenging task because the SNR is poor, due to low contrast and some tails going out of focus. I would try "coherence enhancing filters".

Comment: Actually, I want to calibrate these kind of shapes to identify the degree of curvature of the sperm tails and this picture is the worst one which I could hardly identify. However, I believe that it's worth optimizing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are the sperm tails always green-blue on a gray background? In that case, you can use simple segmentation.

First convert the image to HSV, if the H value is in a range for blue/green, mark it as foreground.

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('img.jpg')

hsv = cv2.cvtColor(img,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([50, 10, 10])
upper = np.array([120, 255, 255])
mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, lower, upper)
res = cv2.bitwise_and(img,img, mask= mask)
cv2.imwrite('test.jpg', res)

kernel = np.ones((5,5), np.uint8)  # note this is a horizontal kernel
d_im = cv2.dilate(mask, kernel, iterations=1)
e_im = cv2.erode(d_im, kernel, iterations=1)

cv2.imwrite('d.jpg', d_im)
cv2.imwrite('e.jpg', e_im)
```

[image: "test.jpg", just the image mask applied][image: "d.jpg", image mask with dilation][image: image mask with dilation and erosion]

Images in order are: image with mask applied, image mask with dilation, and image mask with erosion.

Comment: If you first edit the image to increase contrast and saturation, the results will probably be even better.

Comment: Furthermore, does it mean that I could just modify the lower and the upper thresholds if the target is not green-blue?

Comment: and just one more question, could you teach me how to determine the lower and upper thresholds? Does it mean I should determine the target‘s RGB and use cvt.Color(target_RGB, BGR2HSV) to get the HSV and then determine the lower and upper parameters?

Comment: @MeganHardy Great and compact solution !!

Comment: @RafaelHuang that's one way to go about doing it.  I chose those values by using an BRR/HSV converter online, I also noticed the image had very low saturation and vibrance all over, but especially in the background, so that's why I chose 10 for those lower bounds.  I did a little bit of guess and check here.

Comment: @MeganHardy Does it mean actually we will use some experience if the target and background changed

Comment: you could automatically set those parameters by finding the mode of the BGR values for example - the mode will align with the background and then you can segment the background (rather than the foreground) but in the same manner.

Answer (score 0):

You might want enhance your image before performing any operation. Going through [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unsharp_masking#Digital_unsharp_masking), I came across the following formula for unsharp-masking:

**sharpened = original + (original − blurred) × amount**

Assuming `amount = 1`, I wrote the following snippet:

```
#--- resized the image (too big !!!) ---
im = cv2.resize(im, (0, 0), fx = 0.3, fy = 0.3)

#--- smoothen the image ---
blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (23, 23), 0)

#--- applied the formula assuming amount = 1---
cv2.imshow('sharpened', cv2.add(im[:,:,1], (im[:,:,1] - blur[:,:,1])))
```

This is what I got:

[image]

The tails are a lot more visible now. Use this to further enhance your detection mechanism.

Comment: I have tried your method, and I updated the question, you could have a look. Did I use some wrong steps?

Comment: By the way, I found that the result will be better without the GaussianBlur(), and could you tell me why we should resize the picture before we enhance it.

Comment: @RafaelHuang I resized the image just for convenience, nothing else.

Comment: Okay, and could you teach me how to identify the tails, I have tried your methods and the result I have uploaded in the question.

Comment: Furthermore, I look the gray  picture, and I find that L(background) is around 156, however L(tails) is around 150, which means that the threshold method may be useless. Do you have any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of creative ways to go about edge detection for high frequency edges (like sperm tails for example)

I recommend cv2.Canny() for general edge detection - you will have to play around with the inputs for your specific application.

Alternatively, you can do a difference of gaussian, where you take cv2.GaussianBlur() with two different sigmas and take the difference (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_of_Gaussians)
i.e,

```
blur1 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5,5), sigmaX_1, sigmaY_1)
blur2 = cv2.GaussianBlur(im, (5,5), sigmaX_2, sigmaY_2)
DoG_edge = blur1 - blur2
```

One final possibility is that you could also try some histogram manipulation to enhance the tails of the sperm.

Comment: I tried to use original picture: image to minus the DoG, the result might a little better than the previous one, but still could not identify the full tails.